# Convex quadrilateral inscribed in a circle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math, circles, quadrilateral

> Let $A_0BC_0D$ be a convex quadrilateral inscribed in a circle $\omega$. For all integers $i\geqslant 0$, let $P_i$ be the intersection of lines $A_iB$ and $C_iD$, let $Q_i$ be the intersection of lines $A_iD$ and $BC_i$, let
> $M
> _i$
> be the midpoint of segment
> $P
> _i
> Q
> _i$
> , and let lines
> $M
> _i
> A
> _i$
> and
> $M
> _i
> C
> _i$
> intersect
> $\omega$
> again at
> $A
> _{i+1}$
> and
> $C
> _{i
> +
> 1}$
> , respectively. The circumcircles of
> $\triangle
> A
> _3
> M
> _3
> C
> _3$
> and
> $\triangle
> A
> _4
> M
> _4
> C
> _4$
> intersect at two points
> $P$
> and
> $M$
> . If
> $A
> _0
> B$ = $3$,
> $B
> C
> _0$ = $4$,
> $C
> _0
> D$ = $6$,
> $D
> A
> _0 $= $7$,
> then
> $PM$
> can be expressed in the form
> $\frac{a
> \sqrt{b}}{c}$
> for positive integers $a,b,c$ such that $\gcd(a,c)=1$
> and $b$ is squarefree. Compute $100a +10b+c$ .

Note: a square-free integer (or squarefree integer) is an integer which is divisible by no perfect square other than 1

It's a problem from https://gonitzoggo.com/archive/problem/433/english
I'm taking preparations for junior math olympiad contest and recently I came across this problem.

I've done some calculations but I'm not sure about it. By drawing the figures I've figured out that PM is diameter of the circle. Then I calculated the diameter and that is $\frac{3\sqrt{4830}}{28}$ . so $a=3, b=4830$ and $c=28$ where $\gcd(a,c)=1$ . And So, $100a+10b+c=48628$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange. To get a favourable response and avoid negative attention (downvotes and votes for closing this question), please add context: where you found this question , what’s your level of mathematical education (high school, college, selfstudy, etc etc ), and most importantly  **what you have tried to solve this problem and at which step and where EXACTLY you’re stuck**. You can [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4502306/edit) this question to add the details. Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 for further assistance

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Please see [this tutorial on MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/409) formatting to make your question easier to read. In particular, surround math expressions with dollar signs (`$...$`), and use an underscore (`_`) to make subscripts. So, for instance, your question would start by mentioning quadrilateral `$A_0 B C_0 D$`, which would appear as $A_0BC_0D$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is from the Online Math Open Spring 2020 Competition. It was a late problem, #28, and it's very difficult. There are some solutions on the AoPS thread here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c487h2055659. The idea is to first show that all $P, Q$ lie on $P_0Q_0$ (easiest way is projective). You can also show that $UV$ has the same length as the common chord of $(A_0M_0C_0), (A_1M_1C_1)$ (again, projective and basic radical axis facts help here). These are a few basic observations, the rest should be a length bash (although I think you might need a few more easier facts).